# How to aggregate values in one column for the same values in a different one in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset looking like this:

| country | company_name | company_size | company_activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE | McDonalds | 50 | food |
| FR | McDonalds | 50 | food |
| NL | 7 eleven | 5 | food |

I want to get it into this format:

| country | company_name | company_size | company_activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE,FR | McDonalds | 50 | food |
| NL | 7 eleven | 5 | food |

I have this code:

```
df_cross = df.groupby(["company_name"]).agg({"country": ",".join, "company_activity": ",".join, "company_size": "first"}).reset_index().groupby(["country"]).agg({"company_name": "first", "company_activity": ",".join, "company_size": "first"}).reset_index()
```

This is not giving me my full dataset back though plus the code feels too long. Does anyone have a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: df_cross you're creating it double hta's why you see it as long , from the first rest_index() delete the rest of the code

Comment: @RanA thank you, indeed it works then. I did not see that somehow haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RanA this is the solution:

```
df_cross = df.groupby(["organization_name"]).agg({"country": ",".join, "source_website": "first", "advertiser_type":"first", "organization_activity": ",".join, "organization_size": "first"}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(df.groupby(['company_name'])
          .agg({'country': lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x.tolist())), "company_size": "first" , "company_activity": "first"})
          .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    company_name    country company_size    company_activity
0   7               NL      5               food
1   Mc              DE,FR   50              food
```